# Swift : if statement with multiple text

Tags: swift, if-statement

my problem in text :

I have three arrays one have cars company name ["Toyota","Audi","Nissan"] , the other one have car module number ["2008","2009","2010","2011","2012"], and the last one have cars name ["Camry","Landcruser"].

I want a short clean method to do the following :

if input (1) was ["Nissan"] and input (2) was ["camry"] and input (3) was **"2008" until "2011"** {
result.text = "some text"
}

I did all thing right but my problem is in this code[ "2008" until "2011" ] how can I do this with if ?

here is my code :

```
if (carCompass.text  == "Nissan") && (carTpass.text  == "camry") && (carMpass.text  == "2008") || (carMpass.text  == "2009") || 
    (carMpass.text  == "2010") || (carMpass.text  == "2011") || 
    (carMpass.text  == "2012") && (calc_color.backgroundColor == UIColor(red: 0.2078, green: 0.4471, blue: 0.349, alpha: 1.0))  {

    result.text = " \(landcruzer08_18)" + "L" + "\(landcruzer08_18*1.37) SAR"
}
```

its work fine , but I think its not clean or professional

Comment: Actually that kind of query is the basic purpose of a database

Comment: `(calc_color.backgroundColor == UIColor(red: 0.2078, green: 0.4471, blue: 0.349, alpha: 1.0)` that's really sketchy. Why are you branching based on some arbitrary color?!

Comment: And try to avoid mixing your business logic (car stuff) with facets of your UI (button colors?).

Comment: if the color of the button was red than the result will be deferent than the other result if the button is Green :( I don't find a better way

Comment: @Ahmed You shouldn't be using UI colors to encode state in your application like that. Make a proper state variable, like an enum, to store that state

Comment: I will try and search for that , thank you , I'm a beginner so .. :)

Comment: can you give me a keyword can make it easier for me to start searching

Comment: @Ahmed I don't know what keywords to use, but it's the general category of software architecture/design

Comment: @Ahmed I think this will be a good place for you to start https://medium.com/@johnsundell/modelling-state-in-swift-3751a4acb8f3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor your car data into a properly typed struct (e.g. with the year as an `Int`, rather than a `String`), and use a range operation:

```
if car.make == "Nissan", car.model == "Camry", 2008...2011 ~= car.year {
    result.text = " \(landcruzer08_18)L\(landcruzer08_18*1.37) SAR"
}
```

If you need to choose one of many options, you can use a `switch`:

```
switch (car.make, car.model, car.year) {
    case ("Nissan", "Camry", 2008...2011):
        result.text = " \(landcruzer08_18)L\(landcruzer08_18*1.37) SAR"

    case ("Honda", "Civic", 2005...2015):
        //...
}
```